# Custom Dynamic Routing using Spring Cloud Gatway + Eureka without service name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to automate routing in Spring cloud gateway by discovery with Eureka. Right now with this current configuration I am able to get to the endpoint with the service name, Is there a way I can do this without the service name ?

For Example if I have to access an endpoint in  test-service, my URL is localhost:8100/test-service/test/
Is there a way I can make this localhost:8100/test to route to the same service ?

`spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true`

Comment: Yes, you can customize the predicates and filters but `/test` would have to come from somewhere, either convention or metadata. I can try and show an example later.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you.